# read.csv skipping a column despite presence of a comma

Tags: r

```
str = "a,34° 49' 00\" S,58° 32' 00\" W,c,d"  
read.csv(textConnection(str), header = F)
#prints:
#V1                        V2 V3 V4
#1  a 34° 49' 00 S,58° 32' 00 W  c  d
```

column V2 is `"34° 49' 00 S,58° 32' 00 W"`. Why is read.csv combining this into one column when there is a comma separating it into two?

What should I change for it to return:

```
V1              V2            V3 V4 V5
1  a 34° 49' 00 S  58° 32' 00 W  c   d
```

Comment: Note that `read.csv(text = str, ...)` can be used in place of `textConnection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the comma is quoted. Simply use `quote = NULL`:

```
read.csv(textConnection(str), header = F, quote = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

The string has quote marks embedded in it, just get read.csv to ignore them:

```
> read.csv(textConnection(str), header = F,quote="")
  V1            V2            V3 V4 V5
1  a 34° 49' 00" S 58° 32' 00" W  c  d
```